# Add category slug as class attribute in a link array

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, customization, permalinks, slug

This incredible website and the genius developers here have helped me significantly in the course of my WP Dev over the years, firstly THANK YOU.

I am now faced with a problem that I have been trying to find a solution to for the past 3 days and is driving me insane, but might be easy for one of you genius's!

The problem...

I am using the excellent Microkids Related Posts plugin and I am trying to make a seemingly simple change to the code and the link that is outputted to show the Parent Category Slug of a post as a class, so that I can use it as a global stable unique identifier. The foreach loop is as follows...

```
foreach( $related_posts as $post_type => $post_type_related_posts ) {
    # This filters %posttype% from the title
    $title = MRP_get_title( __($options['title'], 'microkids-related-posts'), $post_type );
    if( count( $post_type_related_posts ) ) {
        $output .= "<div id=\"related-posts-$post_type\" class=\"related-posts-type\">\n";
        # Create the title with the selected HTML header
        $output .= "<".$options['header_element'].">".$title."</".$options['header_element'].">\n";
        $output .= "<ul>\n";
        # Add related posts
        foreach( $post_type_related_posts as $related_post ) {
            $output .= "<li>";
            $output .= "<a href=\"".get_permalink( $related_post->ID )."\">".$related_post->post_title."</a>";
            $output .= "</li>\n";
        }
        $output .= "</ul></div>\n";
    }
    # If there are no related posts for this post type
    else {
        if( !$options['hide_if_empty'] ) {
            $output .= "<div id=\"related-posts-$post_type\" class=\"related-posts-type\">\n";
            $output .= "<".$options['header_element'].">".$title."</".$options['header_element'].">\n";
            $output .= "<p>".$options['text_if_empty']."</p>\n";
            $output .= "</div>";
        }
        else {
            # Show nothing
            return "";
        }
    }
}
$output .= "</div>";
return $output;
```

In the inner foreach loop is the line...

```
$output .= "<a href=\"".get_permalink( $related_post->ID ."\">".$related_post->post_title."</a>";
```

I would like to add a class in the "a" containing the Category Slug so that I can reference that later.

1. my-domain/photo-shoot-location/knights-3/
2. my-domain/press/knights-3/
3. my-domain/photo-meta-data/knights-3/
4. my-domain/about/knights-3/ etc.

I would like for it to look as follows...

```
$output .= "<a class=\" THE-CATEGORY-SLUG \" href=\"".get_permalink( $related_post->ID )."\">".$related_post->post_title."</a>";
```

With `THE-CATEGORY-SLUG` to be "`photo-shoot-location`" or "`press`" etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much in advance!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys found the solution myself (5 days later, oof) added below to help someone else in the future...

```
foreach((get_the_category( $related_post->ID )) as $category) {                             
    $output .= "<a class=\"$category->slug\"  href=\"".get_permalink( $related_post->ID )."\" title=\"" . $category->cat_name . "\">" . $category->cat_name . "</a>";
}
```

Basically the old link above looked like this...

```
$output .= "<a href=\"".get_permalink( $related_post->ID )."\">".$related_post->post_title."</a>";
```

I took the link and added it in a `foreach` loop of it's own. Then I prepared the foundations by calling the get_the_category for the related_post by it's ID. That then gave me access to everything that the $category hook in WP offer, so I then simply call $category->cat_name for the category name and in turn $category->slug for the category slug name.

How cool is WP, VERY COOL!!! Anyway hope this help somebody out there.

Answer (score 0):

Extra bonus Easter Egg for those in need...

After the `foreach` loop by adding...

```
$output .= get_post_field('post_content', $related_post->ID);
```

You will also get the current post content.